# How do I zip a large file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that is 12GB and I'd like to compress it in Python 2.7.x.

I tried to do it with this code

`shutil.make_archive(output, 'zip', input)`

I got back this error

```
LargeZipFile: Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions
```

I read the docs and it says

```
ZIP files that are more than 4 GByte in size require Zip64
```

How do I apply Zip64 to my file?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) there is an extra flag in the ZipFile class to enable the Zip64 extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
shutil.make_archive(output, 'zip', input,allowZip64=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is a Zip 64?

Comment: The original .ZIP format had a 4 GiB (232 bytes) limit on various things (uncompressed size of a file, compressed size of a file, and total size of the archive), as well as a limit of 65,535 (216) entries in a ZIP archive. In version 4.5 of the specification (which is not the same as v4.5 of any particular tool), PKWARE introduced the "ZIP64" format extensions to get around these limitations, increasing the limits to 16 EiB (264 bytes). In essence, it uses a "normal" central directory entry for a file, followed by an optional "zip64" directory entry, which has the larger fields

Comment: This did not work because it gave me the error `TypeError: make_archive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowZip64'`

Comment: I also do not see that option in the docs https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive

Comment: I upgraded my code to Python 3.x and it works, thank you!